# Reset cookie through ajax in php created in php using setcookie method

Tags: php, ajax, cookies

i have create a cookie using setcookie method in php. i want to reset this cookie using ajax. but this doesn't work. if any one have an idea. please help.

Thanks,

Comment: why do you want to use ajax if all cookies available directly from javascript?

Comment: and why not to *debug* your code to find out why doesn't work? Or you think someone has a magic ball here to see what is your problem or what?

Answer (score 0):

You should reset it on the client side, no need for ajax call. For example, you can write it in javascript this way:

```
function del_cookie(name) {
document.cookie = name +
'=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```